# Return inside express router middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, return

If I have a simple express router that just returns nothing (undefined), is there a way to recover from it or will the request just hang until there's a timeout?

For example if I had this code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('stuck');
    return;
});

app.use(router);

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

The app hangs after printing `stuck`. If I return `next()` the request continues, but I'm trying to see if there's a way to recover from an empty return statement without calling `next()` at some point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just call `next()` before you return?

Comment: Yeah in this arbitrary example I totally could. I'll edit the question to make it more clear that I'd like to recover without `next` being called. In the real-world context I'm using this, there's no way to enforce `next` being called, but I'd like to still recover

Comment: You can't recover without `next()` unless you're going to disallow any asynchronous code in the handler.  If there's asynchronous code in the handler, then it will return BEFORE the async code is done.  That's why `next()` has to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to call `next()`, you could probably wrap the handler.

Something like this:

```
const withReturnNext = (func) => (req, res, next) => {
    func(req, res);
    next();
}
app.use(withReturnNext((req, res) => res.set('x-headername', 'value'));
```

However, this is not advisable because any async code will return before the asyncronous action is finished, leading to `next()` being called before it was supposed to.

Comment: This won't work if the handler uses any async code because it will call `next()` BEFORE the async code finishes and does its thing.

Comment: Yes, i mentioned that in the disclaimer at the bottom

Comment: So you posted an answer that "is not advisable"?

Comment: Well, this is what the OP asked for.

Comment: However, this code could still be used if you want to quickly add a header on a response. It would work perfectly well in that case, you would just have to be careful that you didn't use any async code

Comment: Well, the OP didn't say anything about async code in the handler in their question.  It's unclear whether they are aware of that issue or not?

Comment: Fair, in this case there is a chance of async code, though I appreciate the answer for synchronous code

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `next()` to continue the middleware chain. If you return from the function you just terminate the chain and if subsequent function is responsible for the response you won't get it. If you want to terminate (for example because something went wrong) but still finish the request you can use something like that:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something went wrong')
})
```